# Insert image with Rich Text

Tags: text, insert

Whe im using the Rich Text plugin to insert a image it shows not the image directory, but this after clicking the source button.

http://nicoderks.com/shots/gallery-images/2014-10-12_003056.jpg

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Regards,
Nico